# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: objective-c, exception, error-handling

2015-07-03 22:13:37.230 Hyponerd[64413:2308636] loaded its view
2015-07-03 22:13:39.860 Hyponerd[64413:2308636] -[BNRHyposisView MySegmentedControlAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcbd27623b0
2015-07-03 22:13:39.866 Hyponerd[64413:2308636] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BNRHyposisView MySegmentedControlAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcbd27623b0'
*** First throw call stack:

What does this mean? I've been trying to solve this four hours
My code is:

```
    @implementation BNRHyponosisViewController

    -(void)loadView {
        //Create a view
        CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        _backgroundView = [[BNRHyposisView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    NSArray *colors = @[@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green"];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:colors];

    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(40, 200, 250, 50);
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    [_backgroundView addSubview:segmentedControl];

    [segmentedControl addTarget:_backgroundView    action:@selector(MySegmentedControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.view = _backgroundView;

}
          -(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:  (NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
              self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

       if (self) {
            self.tabBarItem.title = @"Hypnotize";

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hypno.png"];

        self.tabBarItem.image = image;

    }   return self;
}
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         NSLog(@"loaded its view");

}
    -(void)MySegmentedControlAction:(UISegmentedControl*)segment
{
        if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [_backgroundView setCircleColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [_backgroundView setCircleColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    } else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        [_backgroundView setCircleColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you're sending an event to a View instead of your ViewController, replace this

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:_backgroundView action:@selector(MySegmentedControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

with this

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentedControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and it should work